# GDAL_CALC weird results

Tags: gdal-calc

Can anyone explain why for gdal_calc results differ in the two cases below?

case 1: (A>0)-(A<10)+(A>0)-(A<10)
case 2: ((A>0)-(A<10)) + ((A>0)-(A<10))

Mathematically speaking, the two should give the very same result.

With gdal_calc, instead, in case 1 I unexpectedly obtain a raster of zeros and ones.
In case 2 I obtain a raster of zeros and twos, as wished.

Comment: I am not sure, but this may not have anything to do especially with GDAL and gdal_calc.py but rather with numpy.